# Firebase Firestore Security Rules: Why are these basic rules not allowing access?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a fairly simple Firestore with these collections:

```
households/entries
users
```

[image]

To my understanding, this should allow everyone access to my collections:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // match /{document=**} {
    //   allow read, write;
    // }
    match /households/{household} {
        allow read, write;
      
      match /entries/{entry} {
        allow read, write;
      }
    }
    match /users/{user} {
        allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

However, it is not. What am I doing wrong?

(The commented out section would allow me access, but I want to use the others to add conditions more granularly.)

Comment: Security rules mean nothing without knowing the QUERY.  How are you trying to access?

Comment: Hi @Julian, Have you encountered any error when you emulate the rules to the [Rules Playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator)?

Comment: @LeadDreamer: Of cause. When I added my logic and it didn't work, I thought to strip it back to the most basic setup I could think of - this. When this also didn't work, I came here.

Comment: @Marc Anthony B: I didn't know about the playground and will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: What we mean is, we can't guess at the behavior of your rules without actually SEEING the queries - you will need to add the queries that are failing HERE, and what errors you are seeing HERE for us to possibly help.